# How to execute a SQL-query which contains multiple queries using $wpdb->query?

Tags: query, wpdb

I want to execute the following Query-String, which contains 2 separate queries using $wpdb->query:

> CREATE TABLE `foobar` ( `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `foo` varchar(22) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;INSERT INTO `foobar` VALUES ('1','foo! mit so \' kram halt')

The query function returns just false and neither the table nor its row were created.

I helped me out by splitting the string into pieces using explode and execute each query separately:

```
$querString = "CREATE TABLE `foobar` ( `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `foo` varchar(22) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;INSERT INTO `foobar` VALUES ('1','foo! mit so \' kram halt')";

$queries = explode(';', $queryString);

foreach($queries as $query) {
  $wpdb->query($query);
}
```

That leads me to the question, why i can't i execute multiple-queries grouped in a string using `$wbdb->query`?

Comment: Almost always in these cases, a custom post type or taxonomy would be safer, faster to implement, and more efficient thanks to the internal caching system. If you really must create a custom database table, use `dbdelta`, and if you want to execute multiple queries, use separate strings or an array instead of `explode`. A custom post type and taxonomy will give you templates, archives, filtering, query vars, caching, APIs, a free admin UI, and allow you to use WP_Query to grab items, as well as plugin support, and in the future, REST API support

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell, thanks for your advice, which is very interesting, but my use case is a little bit different from what you might think. I want to store SQL-dumps from customers in the database to restore them later on. Because of the diversity of SQL, i wont try to port an SQL-dump to an array, only to store it now and use dbdelta afterwards. That might be an option later on, for sure!, but now, its only for a prototype. Do you have a guess, why multiple SQL statements can't be executed via $wpdb->query?

Comment: I will only say that WPDB was never intended for executing tens of thousands of queries all at once

Answer (score 1):

Just separate query with ; as if you would be writting them in the normal sql editor. it should work. I assume your query are not reading query (returning results). they should be for `CREATE`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `ALTER`such kind of queries not `SELECT`

Comment: Hi, i did separate them with ; but the query function returns just false and neither the table nor its row were created. I'd expected the function internally splits queries by ; and execute them sequentially. And yes, my queries or not of type SELECT.

Comment: Can you enable error viewing and see the error being thrown. you can refer to this answer as well. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248998/why-creating-tables-using-wpdb-is-not-being-executed-while-installing-plugins/248999#248999