# why creating tables using $wpdb is not being executed while installing plugins?

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb, activation

This is the code below I am using to create a table when installing plugin. But, I tried many ways and for some reason it is not working. Is there any other efficient way of doing this? Please Help, thanks in Advanced

```
global $wpdb;
function creating_order_tables() {
    global $wpdb;

    $ptbd_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'printtextbd_order';

    if ($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '". $ptbd_table_name ."'"  ) != $ptbd_table_name ) {

        $sql  = 'CREATE TABLE exone(
                customer_id INT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT,
                customer_name VARCHAR(255),
                order_type VARCHAR(255),
                choosen_template VARCHAR(255),
                order_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
                PRIMARY KEY(customer_id))';

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta($sql);
         echo "hello";
    }
}


register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'creating_order_tables');
```

Comment: please edit the question, define "not working": and add whatever relevant information from your debugging attempts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a different method. WordPress fires a hook during plugin activation `activate_yourplugin/filename.php`. You can use this to create tables.

```
function creating_order_tables() {

    if(!get_option('tables_created', false)) {

        global $wpdb;

        $ptbd_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'printtextbd_order';

        if ($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '". $ptbd_table_name ."'"  ) != $ptbd_table_name ) {

            $sql  = 'CREATE TABLE exone(
            customer_id INT(20) AUTO_INCREMENT,
            customer_name VARCHAR(255),
            order_type VARCHAR(255),
            choosen_template VARCHAR(255),
            order_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            PRIMARY KEY(customer_id))';

            if(!function_exists('dbDelta')) {
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
            }

            dbDelta($sql);
            echo "Tables created...";
            update_option('tables_created', true);
        }
    }
}
add_action('activate_yourplugin/yourplugin.php', 'creating_order_tables');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, Also remember int can have maximum of int(11)

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

// Set table name
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'exone';

$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

// Write creating query
$query =  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  ".$table." (
            customer_id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
            customer_name VARCHAR(255),
            order_type VARCHAR(255),
            choosen_template VARCHAR(255),
            order_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
            )$charset_collate;";

// Execute the query
$wpdb->query( $query );
```